# "Invokedynamic Error when Running OpenNLP on Android (Min SDK 13)"

Tags: android, sdk, build.gradle, opennlp

Compile error

Packaging error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.a.b.a.b.al: ERROR in org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore. ConcurrentRunListener.:(Lorg/ apache/maven/surefire/api/report/ ReporterFactory;ZLjava/util/Map:)V: invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 13):org/apache/ maven/surefire/junitcore/ ConcurrentRunListener.class

Build gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 29

buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.linx.android"

    minSdkVersion 16

    targetSdkVersion 29

    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"

}

buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }

}
```

}

dependencies {

implementation 'org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-tools:1.5.3'

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

}

What's wrong huh? I use en-sent. bin

Comment: Please try a more recent version of OpenNLP > 2.x in your project, see: https://opennlp.apache.org/gradle-dependency.html